# How to perform third party Domain setup on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have set up AD Azure and since I have a domain from a third party hosting provider(re-seller) i needed to assign MX and TX values in order to verify the Domain.

Re-seller refused to manually setup the records in the domain registrar and provided a free shared hosting package for me to setup those values in the control panel which i did with no effort and **successfully verified** the domain name within Azure portal.

I had made all the wire up within azure portal to use the domain i had verified but when i browse y.com i get responses from the Re-seller server instead of Azure.

The only thing i had left to do is to change the NS records which the Re-Seller refused to do so - so far.

Please provide some details of how the request travels in this kind of Domain name setup and what measures should i take in order to use my domain in Azure hosted environment?

Comment: So you set up an Azure Web App with a custom domain name? You mention Azure AD in the question. You verify domains in Azure AD to get them available for usernames. That would not point to any website.

Comment: Yes my goal is to setup Azure AD, WebApp and SQL with custom domain name. 
I need to do a bit more research, however still i don't get it how the client server request would travel if the NS records in the registrar are pointing to the reseller instead of AzureNS records provided for setup.

Comment: You will have to change the NS records to the Azure NS servers on your Re-Seller, and then create the corresponding DNS zone in Azure portal to make dns resolved by Azure instead of the Re-Seller server. More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-getstarted-portal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind a custom domain for your Azure app, you need to do three main steps to map the custom domain to your app( more detail refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name)):

[image]

And if you also want to add a custom domain for Azure AD, you can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-domains-add-azure-portal).